# Preventing caching a random SQL query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, caching, activerecord

I'm trying to choose a random track but want it to avoid matching a specific record.

This is my code, but it keeps returning the CACHE of the query so that the while loop never ends.

```
current_track = Track.find(10)
random_track = Track.limit(1).order("RANDOM()").first

while random_track == current_track
  random_track = Track.limit(1).order("RANDOM()").first
  Rails.logger.debug "getting another random one..." random_track
end
```

What is the best way to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite strange, it's not happening to me locally. Anyway, you can use [`uncached`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/QueryCache.html#method-i-uncached)

```
Track.uncached { Track.order("RANDOM()").first }
```

Note that you don't need to `limit(1)` as `first` already takes a single item.

You also don't need that loop. To take a different track use

```
current_track = Track.find(10)
random_track  = Track.where("id <> ?", current_track.id).order("RANDOM()").first
```

You will save a bunch of unneeded code.

Comment: I'd suggest not to use `uncached` because there is no reason to use it. Something else is broken.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly and while it's good to know the syntax for uncached I completely agree it's better to use the where query!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Do you have any default scopes or caches running?

You can avoid the loop by excluding the `current_track` from the random query. Your solution will also fail if there is just one Track, because the loop will never finish.

```
current_track = Track.find(3)
random_track = Track.where.not(id: current_track).order("RANDOM()").first
```

Please note that the `RANDOM()` order might become expensive if your table grows.

Comment: Sorry I missed your post Pascal, thanks for taking the time to explain it to me. I'd already marked Simone's answer as correct so can only upvote this.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @chris! The answers are the same, just make sure you always have at least two tracks....